# True or not: If a normal subgroup and its quotient are commutative, then the group is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G,*$ be a group and $A,*$ a normal subgroup of $G,*$:
$$ A \triangleleft G  \quad( \equiv \forall g\in G: gA = Ag) $$
Then $G$ is commutative iff A and $\frac{G}{A}$ are commutative.

I can see that the theorem is true in one direction $(\Leftarrow)$, but I'm not sure about the other.
Any hints? Or maybe a counterexample...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. $A_3$ and $S_3/A_3$ are both abelian, but $S_3$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Check $S_3$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

The commutator $G'$, subgroup generated by all $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, is normal and also $G/G'$ is abelian  **in any group**. So, take any non-abelian group to illustrate that your hypothesis aren't enough, meanwhile $G'$ is non-trivial, i.e. $1<|G'|$ and $G'\neq G$.

Comment: this generalizes the adjoint answers

Comment: Well, you need the commutator to be nontrivial.

Comment: je suis d'accord Pedro