# Quotient groups and commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If G is a group with an abelian quotient group G/N, then N is abelian. Justify whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: Think about what happens when $[G : N]$ is prime.

Comment: I know that for G/N to be defined , N must be a normal subgroup.Also if G is abelian then so is G/N .But the converse is not true. What can I deduce from this about N?

Comment: As a concrete, simple example of @D_S 's nice remark, consider $A_{n} \unlhd S_{n}$ for $n \geqslant 4$.

Comment: Please help me out with some more precise explanation.

Comment: Let $G$ be any nonabelian group, and $N = G$.

Comment: Also I know that subgroup of an abelian group is abelian .So in above case, If G is abelian then N will be abelian .If G is non-abelian , then N can be an abelian or non-abelian.Am I right with the second statement?

Comment: Think $S_{n}$ and your favourite subgroup of $S_{n}$... of course your favourite subgroup of $S_{n}$ is $A_{n}$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $A$ be an abelian group, $B$ be a nonabelian group, and consider $G=A\times B$, $N=\{1\}\times B$.

Comment: This question really sounds familiar to me, but I couldn't find a duplicate.

Comment: [Related/directly useful](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1104089/29335) but not the duplicate I was thinking of.